# Button in an Email

Tags: email, html, button

Is it possible to have an email alert fired from Salesforce contain a Button, and then for that Button to send a response back to Salesforce if clicked?  This would be used in a Case/Ticket situation asking the Client for their approval or not.  When they click the button, we have the Case.ThreadId in the email sent back to Salesforce and it will let us update the Ticket.

So, I'm not looking for this to be done for me... but is this even remotely possible?

Does this need to be something that calls a server and then that server updates SFDC?  Or is this something we can do using just HTML?

Any insights to the best practice way for me to tackle this would be great.  I've not dove this deep before in this area. I've been trying to use "Mailto:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will need public force.com site.

You can create unique hyperlink on button. when button is clicked, it will navigate to Force.com site with unique Id.

This would be `Visualforce` page with `Controller`, which will perform necessary action However it may raise security and spamming concern.

Comment: Also, consider encrypting the record ID and not exposing the actual Salesforce ID.

Answer (score 1):

A couple other options:

Since it's a Case you're referring to, perhaps instead of a button, it could be a reply email. That email would contain the thread ID. Instruct the user to "reply above this line with APPROVE or REJECT" something like that would allow you to parse the response associated with that case and take some action.

Use an app built on your website using php or whatever to take the URL and make an HTTP post to Salesforce using the API.

Comment: This is a great idea... and I was considering this.  Similar to how an 'approval' email response works.  However, the Director Support really wants a 'button' that they click.  Essentially I wanted the button to do exactly what you are saying and just send me an "Approve" or "Reject" message so we can change the Case Status appropriately.

Comment: Another kinda weird solution would be to have the button hit a web2case page with nothing but a button on the page. Or maybe 2 buttons "Approve" and "Reject". There would need to be a hidden URL parameter in the button they click so that the Case they create can link appropriately to the original. You'd still need some APEX to process that Case (or it could be Web2Lead for that matter). This may cut down a little bit on development, but the Visualforce and Sites solution really is the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Visualforce Template it might work ! Not sure.